# Is it OK to use display:none to create multiple CSS navbars for a responsive site?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a navbar made entirely out of CSS that works well on large screens but is too big to simply reflow on a mobile device. One of the ideas I had was to simply create a second, mobile-friendly navbar, and place it on top of the desktop version but hide it using display:none. Then, I could use a mobile breakpoint to display the mobile navbar and hide the desktop version.

Is this an acceptable practice with CSS? If not, is there another way to display entirely different navbars for different breakpoints?

Edit: Just to clarify, I am using @media queries for the breakpoints.

Comment: please use css media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries  supported by all smart devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is normal practice to hide or show certain elements with display: none for different breakpoints of media queries.

For more information on media queries and how to use them visit [this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is fine to do it that way. However, just to clarify you should be using CSS media queries to tell the browser when to switch to the different navigation bar.